# R: Using geom_ribbon to shade confidence intervals in a geom_line ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, dplyr, reshape2

The project: I am currently trying to build a Shiny App that allows users to generate charts where they can modify time period examined, select variables to look at by time period and country of interest.

I currently built the app with no issues, however I am struggling to add confidence intervals. I believe this is because the data has been melted from a long to a wide format. See random sample of data below:

```
country_name year   variable        value   variable_low           value_low variable_high       value_high
 Uruguay    2002    v2x_delibdem    0.851   v2x_partipdem_codelow   0.724   v2x_partipdem_codehigh   0.796
 Pakistan   2014    v2x_delibdem    0.248   v2x_egaldem_codelow     0.119   v2x_libdem_codehigh      0.312
 Costa Rica 1992    v2x_delibdem    0.864   v2x_polyarchy_codelow   0.882   v2x_partipdem_codehigh  0.691
 Botswana   2005    v2x_delibdem    0.527   v2x_libdem_codelow      0.518   v2x_libdem_codehigh     0.626
 Brazil     1979     v2x_egaldem    0.116   v2x_partipdem_codelow   0.147   v2x_delibdem_codehigh   0.105
 Uruguay    1975     v2x_egaldem    0.207   v2x_egaldem_codelow     0.178   v2x_polyarchy_codehigh  0.117
 Niger      1970     v2x_libdem     0.154   v2x_egaldem_codelow     0.149   v2x_libdem_codehigh     0.176
 Romania    2009    v2x_partipdem   0.478   v2x_partipdem_codelow   0.422   v2x_polyarchy_codehigh  0.717
 Thailand   1997    v2x_partipdem   0.338   v2x_polyarchy_codelow   0.481   v2x_polyarchy_codehigh  0.617
 Peru       1975    v2x_polyarchy   0.104   v2x_egaldem_codelow     0.076   v2x_partipdem_codehigh  0.078
```

The value_low and value_high are the melted values for variable_low and variable_high. These are the upper and lower bounds for the confidence intervals.

When I run this ggplot2 code:

```
myColors <- brewer.pal(5,"Set1")
names(myColors) <- levels(dat$variable)
colScale <- scale_colour_manual(name = "Variable",values = myColors)

ggplot(filter(dat, country_name == "Argentina", variable %in%c("v2x_delibdem","v2x_egaldem"))) +
geom_line(aes(x=year, y=value, group = variable, color = variable), size = 1)+ 
geom_point(aes(x=year, y=value, group = variable, color = variable), size = 3)+
geom_ribbon(aes(x=year, ymin=value_low, ymax=value_high, group = variable, color = variable), linetype=2, alpha=0.1)+
colScale +
scale_x_continuous(breaks=pretty_breaks(n=10),limits=c(1970,2015))+
scale_y_continuous("Index Score", breaks = scales::pretty_breaks(n = 10),limits=c(0, 1))+
theme(text = element_text(size=15))
```

[This is the result:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kXrT4.png)

Clearly my approach isn't working. I was wondering if anyone had experience adding a confidence interval ribbons around a geom_line chart which plots multiple variables.

Comment: Hi @Joe, I think I might know what's going on, could you put in the aes of geom_ribbon `fill = variable`, it won't fix it but it will help me to see what's wrong

Comment: also looking at your data there are mistakes, check that in your first row, the value is 0.851, but the interval values are both lower 0.724 and 0.796

Comment: Hi @DerekCorcoran, [Here is the result with the added code.](http://i.imgur.com/wQk1HfA.png)

Comment: @DerekCorcoran You were right. This is a data error. The way I transformed the put the high and low variables in the wrong spots. I will correct.

Comment: Thanks @Joe, it seems to me that the plot it's doing what it has to do, it seems that the values are off (check my prior comment). Unfortunately the Argentina values are not in the example you gave, but in the data I see at least 4 rows where the value is not within the CI showed in the low high values 1, 6 , 9 and 10. Check the values for delbdem in argentina, they might be of charts or to tight to notie